# File upload in Rails with form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to do a simple file upload in Rails.

My template:

```
<%= form_tag(controller: "my_controller", action: "change_profile_picture", multipart: true) do %>
   <div class="field">
     <%= label_tag :file %>
     <%= file_field_tag :file %>
   </div>
   <div class="actions">
      <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

My handler:

```
def change_profile_picture
  profile_picture = params[:file]
  File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', profile_picture.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
     file.write(profile_picture.read)
  end
  redirect_to :test, params: { profile_picture: params[:file] }
end
```

The file open sequence there is just taken from the rails tutorial.

My problem is that if I inspect, check the class and everything else on params[:file] it is a String, and the inspect just shows me the string. Example: "my_picture.jpg".

The input does not have any original_filename or any other attributes the file should have gotten.

Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

`form_tag({controller: "my_controller", action: "change_profile_picture"}, multipart: true)`